# Create a child instance that has all the data of an instance of its parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am using a class `Parent` from a third-party library. I want to add some functionality to it, but I don't want to mess with the original code too much (I want to keep my additions separate -- at least for now).

I thought to tackle this by making a child class, and then adding all extra functionality to that. However, a 'full' instance of `Parent` (i.e., one containing data) is not created through a constructor, but through a number of other methods in other classes. `Parent` only has a constructor that makes an empty `Parent` instance:

```
public Parent() {
    ...
}
```

... which won't be useful in the child class constructor. My thought now was to add a copy constructor to `Parent`:

```
public Parent(Parent p) {
    ... make copy ...
}
```

... and then call *that* constructor in the `Child` constructor:

```
public Child(Parent p) {
    super(p);
}
```

Would this be a sensible way to go about this, or are there other preferred methods?

Comment: If `Parent` is from a third party library, then leave it alone untouched.   Is there a reason you can’t (or don’t want to) have the code `... make copy ...` in your `Child` constructor?

Comment: Without seeing more details, I can't say for sure. But my first guess is: `Parent` is a sloppy class and should be rewritten from the ground up. If your class requires a bunch of random methods to be called to get it into a valid state, then that's a massive red flag that needs to be dealt with. If you need to do some setup to initialize a `Parent`, then that partially complete object should be a `ParentBuilder` which then translates (when completed) into a `Parent`.

Comment: Do you need to have an instance of `Parent`, with your additions, to pass to methods which expect a `Parent`? Or do you just want to use the behaviour which has been implemented in `Parent` in your own code? Perhaps you can just compose a `Parent` instance as a field in a class of your own, instead of extending it.

Comment: @racraman As far as I can see, that code could also be in the child class. But I find it cleaner to have that bit in the parent class (and not all fields ar accessible outside the parent, I think). It also somehow feels clumsy to do it in the child class.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am not a very good programmer, so it's a bit difficult for me to say, but it seems that you could be right about the sloppiness. It could also be because it's part of something quite complex. It's research code...

Comment: @tgdavies I thought of that too -- but I really want the child to have all the data of a parent instance, to have all its functionality, and then also some methods of its own. So it should really be an extension.

Comment: It depends on whether you are happy to modify the third-party library. The cost of delegating accessors and other methods to the composed instance of `Parent` is a one-off. Applying your modifications to `Parent` has to be done each time you upgrade that library. If it is not necessary that `Child` `IS-A` `Parent`, composition may well be the better solution.

Comment: (If there is an interface that `Parent` implements, of course `Child` can implement that too)

Comment: @rdv Oof, "research code" is never a good sign. There are researchers who are also good programmers, but in my experience the overlap is small, as most researchers' priority is *not* the code quality but the study itself.

Comment: So the third party library - can you modify it at source ?  Eg, is it open-source, and/or in your organisation ?  If  so, add your code that way - if you have a need to do that, the chances are other people who are using it would do as well.  I really would advise against changing that source locally;  use the jar, don’t touch the source behind it.